# Extract words from text files with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, words

I have an html file with content I can't extract easily with BeautifulSoup because I think it is loaded with Javascript.

```
..."inlineParams":"json","title":"","lNameP":"MYNAME","key":"degree_result_person"},"firstName":"MYFIRSTNAME"...
```

I have multiples names in this file that I would like to extract. Those names are just after "lNameP". Is there any way to do a loop to get all those names (in this case i would like to get MYNAME) ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) code will match exactly what you need:

```
string ='"inlineParams":"json","title":"","lNameP":"MYNAME","key":"degree_result_person"},"firstName":"MYFIRSTNAME"'
import re
pattern = re.compile('\"lNameP"\:"(.*?)"')
match = pattern.search(string).group(1)
print (match)
```

Output:

```
MYNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex?

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\"(lNameP)\"\:\"(.*?)\"')
result = pattern.findall(string)
```

`result[0][0]` would be key and `result[0][1]` would be the value.

Comment: Thanks, it works but when i get results I loose accents. Is there any way to keep accents ?

Comment: what do you mean "loose accents"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that instead of having the accent = "éèà..." I have other letters such as : "Ã©\u002...".